# Clip raster by mask layer not working in QGIS 3.4.2?

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3

I've been successfully using QGIS 2.18.21 to `"clip raster by mask layer"` and then run `v.rast.stats`. However recently `v.rast.stats` has stopped working in QGIS 2.18.1. The log does not show an error, it just causes QGIS to stop responding.

To work around this I downloaded QGIS 3.4.2. However, now when I try to run `"clip raster by mask layer"` it does not work and does not give an error in the log. The same thing happens when I try to run `v.rast.stats`. I've checked that all the layers are in the same CRS.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I have the same experience with QGIS 3.4.2 on Ubuntu. Fill an issue. While the bug is solved you can use gdalwarp from the command line: "gdalwarp -cutline ocutting_layer.shp input.tif output.tif"

Comment: You might try the ClipRasterToPolygon tool in the Whitebox for Processing QGIS plugin.